# How to insert a textbox item into database using linq

Tags: c#, linq

My input box accepts a string of text for example,"abc, bcd". What I want to do is to split the string of text into it's individual text abc and bcd using the comma as separator then, by using linq, insert it into db with each individual text being an entry in the DB by itself.
However, I could not achieve it with the below code. 
I am obtaining a `isAdded=false`. Much to my frustration. Anyone can explain to me here.

```
var SourceSystemToBeInserted = this.TxtCreateAgencySourceSystem.Text.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim())
        .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x))
        .ToArray();


var agencySourceSystemDataOwnerToBeInsertedIntoGovernance = SourceSystemToBeInserted
.Select(AgencySourceSystemToBeInserted => new Governance()
{
    AgencyCode = AgencyCode + "_" + AgencySourceSystemToBeInserted,
    GovernanceCode = AgencyCode + "_" + AgencySourceSystemToBeInserted + "_" + Constants.GOVERNANCE_ROLE_DATA_OWNER_VALUE,
    RoleCode = Constants.GOVERNANCE_ROLE_DATA_OWNER_VALUE,
    CreatedBy = EDHSession.Current.User.EmailAddress,
    CreatedDate = dateTimeNow
})
.Select(agencyGovernance => new
{
    Governance = agencyGovernance,
    IsAdded = userServiceProxy.CreateGovernance(agencyGovernance)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Extension method `Select` returns instance of `IEnumerable<T>` which is lazy executed type.

Actual execution of lambdas you provided will be executed only when you enumerate it by using `foreach` or `ToList()` or other methods

```
var sourceSystems = 
    this.TxtCreateAgencySourceSystem
        .Text
        .Split(',')
        .Select(source => source.Trim())
        .Where(source => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(source) == false)
        .Select(source => new Governance
        {
            AgencyCode = $"{AgencyCode}_{source},
            GovernanceCode = ${AgencyCode}_{source}_{Constants.GOVERNANCE_ROLE_DATA_OWNER_VALUE}",
            RoleCode = Constants.GOVERNANCE_ROLE_DATA_OWNER_VALUE,
            CreatedBy = EDHSession.Current.User.EmailAddress,
            CreatedDate = dateTimeNow
        })
        .Select(governance => new
        {
            Governance = governance,
            IsAdded = userServiceProxy.CreateGovernance(governance)
        })
        .ToList() // here all Selects and Wheres methods will be executed actually



var addedSystems = sourceSystems.Where(system => system.IsAdded)
                                .Select(system => system.Covernance)
                                .ToArray();
```

Comment: I tried your answer but i am still getting false. Thanks.

Comment: What you mean by getting false? If all items contains `IsAdded = false` - then you should show `CreateGovernance` method.

Comment: I found the error. It's some DB constraint. Nvm, thanks a lot. Hey, Fabio, you are of a great help. Hope we can be great coding friend. Learn a lot from you.